# Duplicate GA4 Pageviews with Google Tag Manager Advanced Consent Mode

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4, cookieconsent

I've implemented advanced consent settings in Google Tag Manager (GTM) according to the guidelines provided by Google. However, I'm encountering an issue where each page load results in duplicate pageviews being sent to my Google Analytics 4 (GA4) property.

In GTM's debug mode, I noticed that there are two config being sent, and within each, a pageview event is sent. One of the config events is being triggered before consent is set, even though I have configured all tags to load after consent.

Here's the sequence of events as they appear in debug mode:

[image]

The first config call should not be happening according to my configuration, as I have set up all tags to wait for the consent update before firing.

How can I ensure that only one config and one pageview are sent after consent is granted, and prevent the premature config call? I also checked my recommended events setting in GA4 and made sure all tags are consent configured.

Any insights or troubleshooting tips would be greatly appreciated.